# What happens if a MS CRM Workflow Dynamic Value exceeds the field limits?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2015

I think the title pretty much explains it all. I want to know what happens when a dynamic value exceeds its fields limits in MS CRM Workflows.

For Example;
When using the Create step and creating a Task, a Task description field has a limit of 2000 characters. If I am using this task to show an error, maybe a stack overflow, this may sometimes be more than 2000 characters.

What happens in this situation? Is an error thrown or is the dynamic value limited to 2000 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a few tests I have found my answer. It appears the workflow will throw an error and the system job will sit in waiting.